# can't find '__main__' module in '2_wallie_how_are_you' как решить проблему?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Когда выполняю код ниже - выдает такую ошибку  can't find '**main**' module in '2_wallie_how_are_you' как это решить?

```
import random  


def get_wallie_action():
    possible_actions = [
        'считает новых пользователей',
        'готовит новую задачу',
        'что-то проверяет',
        'придумывает новую ачивку',
        'проверяет чью-то задачу',
        'проставляет ссылки в энциклопедии',
        'вычитывает статью',
        'ищет стажировки для студентов',
    ]
    return 'Валли ' + random.choice(possible_actions)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    action = get_wallie_action()
    print action
```

Comment: Какую IDE используете, случайно не Sublime? И да, в третьем питоне нет ключевого слова `print`, она только во втором, теперь это функция и должна вызываться как функция `print(action)`

Comment: Codeenvy использую

Comment: @David а запускаете как? Попробуйте напрямую через терминал (или командную строку, если Windows)

Comment: Это ошибка не в коде, а в том, как он запускается и выполняется самой IDE. Нашел аналогичное, но оно для Sublime. Проверьте, что созданный файл в IDE имеет расширение *.py. Возможно придется покопаться в настройках программы в разделе интерпретатора.